# Obtaining selected value from QGIS using python algorithm?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm writing an algorithm in python for QGIS and i have a function which uses a value from a selection.
The problem is that when i select a value the script give me the error that the local variable 'subsetOut' referenced before assignment.

This is my code

```
##Raster=group
##imagePath=raster
##gap=number 100
##window=number 31
##distance=number 5
##angle=selection 0;45;90;315

.....

def imageSubset(angle,window, distance, i, j):
    if angle ==0:
        subsetOut=InRaster[i-((window-1)/2):i+(window-((window-1)/2)),j-((window-1)/2):j+(window-((window-1)/2))+distance]
    elif angle ==45 or angle==np.pi/4:
        subsetOut=InRaster[i-((window-1)/2):i+(window-((window-1)/2))+distance,j-((window-1)/2):j+(window-((window-1)/2))+distance]
    elif angle== 90 or angle==np.pi/2:
        subsetOut=InRaster[i-((window-1)/2):i+(window-((window-1)/2))+distance,j-((window-1)/2):j+(window-((window-1)/2))]
    elif angle==315 or angle == -(7*np.pi/4):
        subsetOut=InRaster[i-((window-1)/2)-distance:i+(window-((window-1)/2)),j-((window-1)/2)-distance:j+(window-((window-1)/2))]
    return(subsetOut)


for i in range((window+1)/2, rowOut*gap+(window+1)/2, gap):
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+"Computing : "  + str(int(float(i)*100/(rowOut*gap))) + '%')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for j in range((window+1)/2, colOut*gap+(window+1)/2, gap):
        sub=imageSubset(angle,window, distance,i-1, j-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only line that is going to generate that error is `return(subsetOut)`

If `subsetOut` is referenced before assignment it means none of the above `if` and `elif` conditions matched as true. There's no `else` to catch anything else.

You seem to be comparing a selection value with a numeric. I suspect the selection values are *character* values (since a selection value can be a number of text options). Comparison of character with numeric yields `False`:

```
>>> "90" == 90
False
```

Fix by converting to the same form.

```
>>> int("90") == 90
True
```

Also, you have another comparison with floating point values, and this is a bad thing most of the time due to floating point precision. Its also a bit weird that `angle` can be degrees or radians.

But anyway, your `if` falls through so `subsetOut` isn't defined and that's probably what's wrong.